# mvc passing data from view to controller

Tags: asp.net-mvc, view

My Controller

```
public class OgrenciController : Controller
{
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult home(int perId)
    {
        if(perId=="anything")
        {
            //something
        }
        return View();
    }
}
```

This is my view

```
@foreach (var item in Model)
{
    siraNo++;
    <form method="post">
        <input type="radio" name="perId" value="@item.specialId">
        <input type="submit" value="send" />   
    </form>
 }
```

but in the POST method, `perId` not take anythings

Comment: Your view makes no sense. Why do you have multiple forms with a single radio button? And your `perId` parameter is `int` so how in the world do you ever think it could have a value of `"anything"` (a `string`). And your code wont even compile!

Comment: Show us your  GET method

Comment: in  form there is a missing action like <form method="post" action="Ogrenci/home ">

Answer (score 1):

use something like this.

```
 @using (Html.BeginForm())
 {
        foreach (var item in Model)
        {
           <input type="radio" name="perId" value="@item.specialId"><br /><br />
        }
        <input type="submit" ur value="send" /> 
}
```

Comment: There can be as many `<form>` elements as you want (so long as they are not nested). This does not answer the question